# What does $\| W \|$ mean in math?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, notation, vectors

I've been reading a paper to replicate an experiment and it says that $\| W \| = 1$, where $W$ is the value of a vector that has eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I'm a bit rusty, but I know that $| W |$ is the modulus of $W$, but what exactly is $\| W \| = 1$, for a matrix of $20\times2$ of eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: $$\| {\bf w} \| = \sqrt{{\bf w} \cdot {\bf w}}$$ is the magnitude.

Comment: Ok, so for a matrix of size RxC, the magnitute would be what exactly? C size of 1 or R and C size of 1?

Comment: The tag was always matrices though, was it not? I might even edit my question to make it clear.

Comment: You are saying that $W$ is two things. First, that it's a vector, and then that it's a $20\times 2$ matrix. Which of the two is it? It's also unclear what is meant by "vector that has eigenvalues and eigenvectors". For matrices, $||\cdot ||$ usually denotes a matrix norm, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: @John There are two common meanings to $\|W\|$: one is that they mean the "spectral norm", and the other is that they mean the "Frobenius norm".